# Overwrite CSS in an additional file?

Tags: css, themes, impresspages

Is there a way to overwrite CSS definitions in an additional file (similar to the concept of child themes of WordPress)?

Comment: Yes, any CSS properties you declare after the initial should overwrite them (assuming you do the same level of selectors). If for some reason it is not overwriting, you can use !important. Eg: display: block !important;

Comment: Note that there's a lot of bad information about the order of precedence out there. I recommend reading the cascade rules from the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) itself.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a hierarchy for overrides

1. Styles can be overridden in where the style is defined (inline style within element attribute vs embedded style on same page vs externally referenced style)
2. Overrides can occur through the selection of the element (id, attributes, classes, etc)
3. Order of the definitions - if you have the external stylesheet that needs to be overridden, use your own stylesheet that is referenced after that external stylesheet you want to override
4. Usage of `!important` in the style definition

See: http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence

Comment: great answer, expanded the OPs question to explain CSS hierarchy of declarations which will be way more useful to both the OP and other who find this question in later searches.

Answer (score 0):

...just create a new css file and place it AFTER your initial css style tag in your code.